# Calculate Field in Model Builder does not show join table fields

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, modelbuilder

Using Pro 3.03.  I am using Add Join in Model Builder to join a table to a feature class.  The resulting layer is the input to a Calculate Field tool.  Essentially, I'm trying to calculate a field in the input layer based on a field in the joined table.
In the Calculate Field tool, I'm used to seeing the join table fields (such as JoinTable.FieldName).  Not so now.
I have played around with both Make Feature Layer and Make Table View results feeding into Add Join and even into Calculate Field.  But I still can no longer access the join table fields.  I realize the tool hasn't technically run but I am sure this was possible previously.

[image]

Comment: If you right-click the "Add Join" tool (in the model), and then "Run" just that part of the model, does that enable the "Calculate Field" tool to display the fields that you expect?  (Ie, don't attempt to run the entire model, but only run the "Add Join" tool within the model.)

Comment: @SonofaBeach Nope   Expression builder in Calculate Field only shows fields from the target table, not the input table, even after a Run command in Model Builder

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Anyone found an answer? Frustrating. It works in a webmap, but not in model builder.

Comment: I believe this to be a bug introduced into modelbuilder, I similar issues with the merge and append tool. I have logged it with ESRI and hopefully they will sort it out on the next release.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.0. In the ModelBuilder, I tried all sort of combination (Add Join -> Calculate Field or Make Feature Layer -> Add Join -> Calculate Field) and joined field names do not appear in the Calculate Field geoprocessing tool (in ModelBuilder). However, I opened the layer in the Map Content and right-click the field to calculate and selected all field names to write my calculation. Instead of running the calculate field in the Map, I simply copy & paste the calculation into the Calculate Field in the ModelBuilder. Magic! ModelBuilder did recognize the joined fields and the calculation went well. It may help for the time being as a workaournd.